# Understanding geosynchronous orbits in an otherwise empty universe

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames

Suppose the universe was completely empty except for a rotating planet with a moon in geosynchronous orbit.  How would it be possible to understand why the moon did not fall since there is nothing to compare the rotation of the planet to.  Would an observer not see a moon levitating above a planet?  How would the observer be able to understand what is happening here?

Comment: In an otherwise empty universe the moon will fall on the planet. I think it was Mach, who pointed out that centrifugal forces have to do with the influence of the gravitational field from all the masses of the universe.

Comment: If the planet and moon weren't actually alone but merely distant from any other masses would the result be different?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the observer would notice the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#Applied_to_the_Earth) affecting weather patterns on their planet and infer from that that their planet is rotating.

Comment: Maybe.  On the other hand the planet may be a barren rock.